# Functional sequences and a test for uniformly convergence

Tags: analysis

Hi I was trying to solve a question, consider the following functional sequence:

$ f_{n}:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ , $f_n(x)=\dfrac{x^n}{n+x^n}$

I actually computed that:
\begin{align} 
f_{n} \to f(x)
\end{align} 
\begin{align}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & 0\leq x \leq 1
\\
1 & x>1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
, so I wanna take $Sup$ from $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ ,so if the value of that tends to $0$ then I can conclude that $f_{n}$ tends to $f$ uniformly convergence, but I guess the $ Sup$ does not tend to $0$. I have problem computing the above $Sup$.

\begin{align*}
|f_n(x) - f(x) | = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^n}{n+x^n} & 0 \leq x \leq 1
\\
\dfrac{n}{n+x^n} & x>1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
I wonder how to take $Sup$ from $|f_n(x)-f(x) |$ ?

Comment: Since $f_n$ is continuous for all $n$ and $f$ is not, obviously the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: I know but I wanna use the TEST ... so I need to take Sup ,but I don't know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(n^{1/n})-f(n^{1/n})=\frac 1 2 -1$ so the supremum does not tend to $0$.

Note that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ decreasing in $[1,\infty)$ and increasing in $[0,1]$. So finding the supremum is quite easy.

Comment: I know, I exactly want to compute the supremum...

Comment: @Reza I have edited my answer. Finding sup of a monotone function is trivial. The answer  is $\frac n {n+1}$.